# Get class name of parent div and use that as selector for a new jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an ordered list I created like this:

```
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 value-1">
      <li>This is value 1</li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 value-2">
      <li>This is value 2</li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 value-3">
      <li>This is value 3</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ol>
```

and below this ordered list I have a row of images as such:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-1" src="img1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-2" src="img2.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-3" src="img3.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to write a jQuery function that binds a hover listener to the li elements. When the user hover's over the li element, it will look at the parent div's class and use that class as a selector for another function that sets everything with the class to an opacity of 0.4. So if I over over `<li>This is value </li>` it will set the opacity of `img1.png` to 0.4.

If there is a better way of accomplishing this I would love to learn that way as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your ordered list is **invalid**. Lists must have `<li>`'s as their children.

A better HTML structure for your scenario would be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ol class="custom-counter">
      <li class="col-md-4" data-target="value-1">This is value 1</li>
      <li class="col-md-4" data-target="value-2">This is value 2</li>
      <li class="col-md-4" data-target="value-3">This is value 3</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="value-1" src="img1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="value-2" src="img2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="value-3" src="img3.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.custom-counter li').hover(
  function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('img.' + target).fadeTo("slow", 0.4);
  },
  function() {
    $('img').fadeTo("slow", 1);
  }
);
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/WwLEwm

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use a class for this as the element could have several classes. I would use a data attribute. Also, I would put the data attribute directly on the li and do it like this:

```js
$('[data-target-selector]').hover(function(){
 var target=$(this).data('target-selector');
  
 $(target).css('opacity',0.4);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ol class="custom-counter">
      <li  data-target-selector=".value-1">This is value 1</li>
      <li  data-target-selector=".value-2">This is value 2</li>
      <li  data-target-selector=".value-3">This is value 3</li>
</ol>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this demo in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andersoncontreira/mudew6yg/)

jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".custom-counter li").hover(function(){
        var className = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    var matArr = className.match(/value-\d+/); 
    var mainClass = matArr[0];


    if($("."+mainClass).hasClass("opacityActived")){
        $("."+mainClass).removeClass("opacityActived");
        $("."+mainClass).css("opacity","1");
    }else{
    $("."+mainClass).addClass("opacityActived");
    $("."+mainClass).css("opacity","0.4");
    }


  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/560zgych/) i made for you. have a look.
So basically, with your structure, you wanna get the parent div's class and get the second class out and then do stuff with that class.

```
$('li').hover(
   function() {
      var thisclass = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1];
      $('img.' + thisclass).fadeTo("slow", 0.4);
   },
   function() {
      var thisclass = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1];
      $('img.' + thisclass).fadeTo("slow", 1);
   }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is add a listener class for the items and a data target value for the relation towards the items you want to change. And as you say you want to have the opacity changed I would suggest to add an extra class in order to handle the changes. If there's something else you want to do with it, like a border or such, you can handle that at the same class definition, like so:

```
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 hoverlistener" data-targetclass="value-1">
      <li>This is value 1</li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hoverlistener" data-targetclass="value-2">
      <li>This is value 2</li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hoverlistener" data-targetclass="value-3">
      <li>This is value 3</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ol>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-1" src="img1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-2" src="img2.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="value-3" src="img3.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<style>
   .semi {
      opacity: 0.4;
      filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   }
</style>
<script>
  $("body")
     .on("mouseenter",".hoverlistener",function(){
       var targetClass = $(this).data("targetclass");
       $("."+targetClass").addClass("semi");
     })
     .on("mouseleave",".hoverlistener",function(){
       var targetClass = $(this).data("targetclass");
       $("."+targetClass").removeClass("semi");
     });
 </script>
```